# bootstrap 4 grid - row with slider

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 6 photos and on md size I would like to have a slider to show them all, on lg they are all displayed side by side and on sm they are displayed 1 per row so there is no problem. Basically I am saying that I don't want to have 2 rows on md but 1 with a slider.
Here is how it looks now [image: md size with no slider]

**but I would like to make it look like this**

[image: images with slider]

**the blue line is supposed to be a slider** that slides right to reveal more photos.

This is the code I am using now

```
        <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" id="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/fortnite.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/gta5.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/leagueoflegends.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/mobile legends.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/minecraft.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <img src="./assets/GAMES/rust.jpg" alt="" class="rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is it possible to do? What do i have to learn to do it? Any links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the media query to set the `flex-wrap` and `overflow` for the respective screen width. I have set the minimum width as 768px and max-width as 991.98px. You may change it accordingly. Please run the code snippet for the output.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .row {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row align-items-center text-center">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" id="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/fortnite.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/gta5.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/leagueoflegends.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/mobile legends.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/minecraft.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-12 mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <!-- <img src="./assets/GAMES/rust.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"> -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="rounded">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works exactly as i wanted, i did not know i could do this with css, there are still a lot of things to learn for me :D, thanks a lot!

Comment: Np. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a corousel item (slide) for each of 4 card by using js and use corousel of bootstrap 4 to show sliding row.

[Corousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting up a slider to move around the images, we can actually create a carousel effect with bootstrap. It will provide a breath-taking experience to the users. Here's the code for it.

PS: Edit the class and ID names as per your requirements.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```